# How avoid "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: mongodb, express

I use mongodb and in mongodb I put my username and password.
The code is:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var http = require('http');
var fs=require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.listen(8080, function() {
      console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    });

app.post('/prova', function(req, res) {
//    res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.username + '".');
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    // Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/utente';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
          } else {
            //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
            console.log('Connection established to', url);
            var collection = db.collection('login');

         //   var prova1=({name:"documento1",url:"sadsad",tag:"dc1"});
            // do some work here with the database.
            var cursor = collection.find();

            cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                //  console.log('Fetched:', doc);
                var username=0;
                var password=0;
                  for(valore in  doc){
                      if(valore!="_id"){
                          if(valore=="username"){

                              if(doc[valore]==req.body.username){
                                  username=1;

                              }
                          }
                          if(valore=="password"){

                              if(doc[valore]==req.body.password){
                                  password=1;

                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  if(username==1 && password==1){
                      console.log("entra");
                    //  res.end();
                  }else{
                        fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\Eventi\\Desktop\\Node.js\\Progetti\\ProveNodeJS\\NodeJSProve\\paginaRifiuto.html', function (err, html) {
                            if (err) {

                            }
                        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
                        res.write(html);  
                        res.end(html); 
                        });
                  }
                }
              });
            //Close connection

          }
        });

    });
    http.createServer(function(request, response) { 

        fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\Eventi\\Desktop\\Node.js\\Progetti\\ProveNodeJS\\NodeJSProve\\home.html', function (err, html) {
            if (err) {

            }
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end(); 
        });
    }).listen(8000);
```

I call first `http://localhost:8000` and I put in a text field the wrong value of username and password and after I click login I see my "login fail page" but I obtain this error:

```
Connection established to mongodb://localhost:27017/utente
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:195:21)
    at ServerResponse.writeHeader (_http_server.js:233:18)
    at C:\Users\Eventi\Desktop\Node.js\Progetti\ProveNodeJS\NodeJSProve\HelloWord.js:67:23
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with mongodb. And all - with your `response.writeHeader` calls.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, this is a horribly wrong implementation of a check for correctly provided username/password.

Comment: It has "everthing to do with" the fact that you are trying to send the response mulitple times within a loop though. You cannot do that.